# What does set(str.begin(), str.end()) mean?

Tags: c++

I was going through this question on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/determine-if-two-strings-are-close/solutions/935916/c-o-nlogn-sort-hash-table-easy-to-understand/

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool closeStrings(string word1, string word2) {
        if(word1.size()!=word2.size())
            return false;
        int n = word1.size();
        vector<int>freq1(26,0);
        vector<int>freq2(26,0);
        for(int i= 0 ; i < n ; ++i){
            freq1[word1[i]-'a']++;
            freq2[word2[i]-'a']++;
        }
        sort(freq1.rbegin(),freq1.rend());
        sort(freq2.rbegin(),freq2.rend());
        **if(set(word1.begin(),word1.end())!=set(word2.begin(),word2.end()))**
            return false;
        for(int i= 0;i<26;++i){
            if(freq1[i]!=freq2[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

I am not understanding what does `set(word1.begin(),word1.end())` mean over here, I tried to search on the internet for answer but I didn't got any satisfying answer, if someone can explain it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ask this question on the LeetCode forums?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set - see overload (2). And please don't add irrelevant tags - this question has nothing to do with digital signature algorithm (DSA).

Comment: @Eljay 
Not yet, thanks for suggesting I'll ask there as well.

Comment: (DSA) over here refers to Data structures and algorithms FYI @Evg

Comment: Please read the description of [tag:dsa] tag. It reads: *Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions.*.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of it. Will keep in mind for future reference - @Evg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a `set` of the characters in `word1`, which is just the unique characters and in a way that could be compared to another word without the number of occurrences or order mattering.

So, comparing sets made this way, "cat" and "taca" would have `==` sets. "cat" and "taco" would not. "cat" and "kat" would not, but "dog" and "good" would.

So, this code is saying that if the words do not share all of the same letters, then they would not be considered *close*.

Answer (score 2):

Strings can be thought of as containers for `char`. Thus it's possible to define iterators for them (that visit them in-order, char-by-char). `word1.begin()` and `word1.end()` are simply the iterators to the first character and to the end of string.

Other containers can usually be initialized using iterator pairs (begin, end), thus `set(word1.begin(),word1.end())` means a `std::set<char>` of the characters of the string. Set in C++ means ordered collection of unique elements; their comparison returns true iff all elements are the same. Thus, in the `if` statement, you compare if both strings contain the same characters (but maybe multiple times and in different order).